# Expand rest of the div to show the full content (onClick with buttons)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a div that has some content in its collapsed form, expands on a button click, shows the additional content (div's full form), and offers a button again at the end to close the expanded box.

This is what i have

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}


.collapsible:after {
  content: '+';
  color: black;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}



.active:after {
  content: "-";
}
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0s ease-out;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">Title 1</button>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>



<button class="collapsible">Title 2 <br>   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</button>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```

The second div in the example is me trying to explaining what i am trying to achieve and which could almost work well enough for me even it is technically wrong (since there would be no bg colour so no one would see the actual div structure) but the collapse button eventually exposes the mess by appearing in the middle of it all.

Comment: Yes, you have an idea?

Comment: I hope my idea is helpful to you. If you have any further questions, please add a comment beneath my answer.

Comment: yes! thank you! i managed to butcher it and get what I want haha

Comment: is it possible to put the button at the end of the box instead at the top? whatever i tried so far isn't working @gibberish

Comment: Use the method I used to position the `smallx` div in the second example. first, the parent div must be `position:relative` (or `absolute` or `fixed`, just not the default which is `static`). As a matter of course, when I start a new project, my first line of css is `* {position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;}. ***THEN*** use `position:absolute;` along with `top`, `left` or `right`, and maybe `z-index` to position the element where I want it. You can do that with a `<button>` or with a `<div>` or etc - and you can style a div to look and act like a button, so don't get hung up on buttons :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example, using jQuery.

The example uses two different types of open/close triggers, so that you can see a couple of options. Note how CSS is used to create the second *button*.

`$('button, .smallx')` means that ***both*** the button element ***and*** the element with `class="smallx"` are watched for user click events.

When either one of these is clicked, we search back up the DOM tree to the first element with class `.container`, then from there were search for an element with class `content`. We assign *that* element to a variable called "box". The rest is self-explanatory (just adding/removing a class).

```js
$('button, .smallx').click(function(){
  let box = $(this).closest('.container').find('.content');
  if ( box.hasClass('collapsed') ){
    box.removeClass('collapsed');
  }else{
    box.addClass('collapsed');
  }
});
```

```css
*{position:relative;}
.container{max-width:300px;margin-bottom:20px;overflow:hidden;}
.collapsed{max-height:50px;}

.smallx{position:absolute;top:3px;right:3px;padding:3px;border:1px solid dodgerblue;cursor:pointer;z-index:1;}
.smallx:hover{border:1px solid green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button class="collapsible">Title 1</button>
  <div class="content collapsed">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="smallx"> X </div>
  <div class="content collapsed">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
```